# Finding a general solution to a first order linear differential equation, using the integration factor method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a very simple ODE using a integrating factor, I have a solution but its trivial and I'm unsure how to find the general solution.

$$\tau \frac{dV}{dt} = E_0 - V$$
Where $E_0$ and $\tau$ are constants. I do the following

\begin{align}
\tau \frac{dV}{dt} &= E_0 - V &\implies \\
\frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{V}{\tau} &= \frac{E_0}{\tau} 
\end{align}

Then the integrating factor is $e^{v(t)}$ where $v(t) = \int\frac{dt}{\tau} = \frac t\tau$ so the integrating factor is $e^{{t} / {\tau}}$. Then the solution is given by $$V(t)  =e^{{-t} / {\tau}} \int e^{{t} / {\tau}} \frac{E_0}{\tau}   =e^{{-t} / {\tau}}  e^{{t} / {\tau}} E_0 = E_0   $$

This is a solution since $$\tau \frac{dE_0}{dt} = 0 = E_0 - E_0$$

But I was expecting a more general solution such as $$V = C + Ee^{-t / \tau}$$ without having to "guess" it, can somebody please give me some direction?

Comment: When integrating $\int e^{{t} / {\tau}} \frac{E_0}{\tau} \ dt$ be sure to put in an arbitrary constant. (This is one of the reasons the integration constant $+C$ is drummed into us early in our calculus education!)

Comment: Wow that was such a school boy error. Thank you @SimonS .

Comment: I assume that adding a constant when working out $v(t)$ won't add anything to the general solution and just make the calculation longer, so I can let the constant of integration $0$ there ?

Comment: I'm not following you. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from above, the general solution is

$$V(t)  =e^{{-t} / {\tau}} \int e^{{t} / {\tau}} \frac{E_0}{\tau} \ dt    = E_0 e^{-t/\tau} \left( e^{t/\tau} + C' \right) = E_0 + Ce^{-t/\tau}  $$

(where $C = E_0C'$)